# How to get next 3 characters after a substring if it exist inside a string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string `that&#39;s`. The `&#` substring is common but number after it changes in almost every object of my JSON data. So I want to detect if there is this substring, then get next three characters after it replace it with something else. How can I do it?

Comment: isn't easier just run this string through some html decoder?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var para = 'that&#39;s';
para = para.substr(para.indexOf('#')+1, 3);
```

syntax:

```
substr(start, length)

indexOf(searchvalue, [start])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to replace everything from `&#` until `;` (if not, please update your question by specifying expected output):

You can use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regular expression:

```js
var para = 'some string &#39; middle &#134; end';
para = para.replace(/&#([\d]*);/g, 'replacement');
```

The `g` modifier is important to replace all occurences in the string.

With the RegEx used, you can include the found number (between `&#` and `;`) in the replacement string by using `$1`.

Comment: My desired output is; when ther is substring &# replace everything starting from that substr till `; `

Comment: Still unclear, should the replaced string include the delimiters?

Input: 'that&#39;s', replacement string: 'X', desired output: 'thatXs'

If yes then my code should work. You can test it on your browser's Devtools console.

Comment: OK I solved it, but instead of * I used + as @penguintheorem suggested. Thanks for bot of you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can define and use a utility function to replace [HTML entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html) like that:

```
function decode(text, replaceWith = '') {
 return text.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, replaceWith)
}
```